# Databricks Autoloader resucues an all null column

Tags: azure, function, null, databricks, autoload

We are parocessing some txt files to parquet using Azure Functions. The parquet files are then read by Databricks Autoloader. In order for the Autoloader to read values that are blank/empty in the original txt file as `null`s, we have set the functions to parse any blank/empty value into `None` otherwise they will be read as emptly/blank values and this will not be consistent across the entire dataset as columns of other data types e.g. date are automatically being read as `null` by the Autoloader if they are empty. The problem is that when an entire column (string or double) has null values the Autoloader keeps pushing them all to the _rescued_data column. This doesn't happen on the columns where empty/blank values are automatically being read as `null` it rather only happens where we have parsed them to `None` in the function. Is there any way to resolve this i.e. to get Autoloader read blank/empty values as `null` but when an entire column has `null`s it doesn't get rescued?

The Azure function is assigning string column types using a nullable_str() lambda function as below:
def nullable_str():
return lambda x: str(x) if x != '' else None
We don't want to use '' instread of None (that would cause inconsistency across entire columns).

Comment: can you share your code and share if there is any error?

Comment: Hi @DileeprajnarayanThumula
`def nullable_str(): return lambda x: str(x) if x != '' else None`
We do not get any error no. it's just if a column is entirely `null` in a file, the Autoloader rescues the whole column and as we have other logics set to monitor the rescued data it gets irritating.